# have mouse move proportionately between two screens?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a computer with two screens..  A laptop with its screen. And another screen that I have connected to it that is much larger.

I can move my mouse from screen 1 (The laptop screen), left to screen 2.

But the problem is that if I move my mouse to near the bottom of screen 2, and right, I cannot get to screen 1. I'd like it so that if my mouse is, at the bottom of screen 2, and I move my mouse right, i'd get to the bottom of screen 1.  And that if my mouse was 5% up screen 2, and I moved it to the right, i'd get 5% u pscreen 1.

At the moment, there is a border the right edge of screen 2 at the portion where there's no screen 1.

If I am at the bottom of screen 1, and I move my mouse left, I don't get to the bottom of screen 2, (as you can see from the ctrl panel display it's obvious why). though i'd like to.

As you can see the way Windows works is the border that is shared by screen 2 and screen 1, no issue. The mouse moves across though if it's half way up one screen and you move it across it may not be halfway up the other screen. But where the border isn't shared, then one screen you hit the border, the other screen you get across.

I would like the screens to relate to each other, so that at any position on one screen you can move to the side to the other screen. So the top of one screen relates to the top of the other screen. The bottom of each screen relate. The middles relate. So that even with different sized screens there isn't a portion of a screen where you can't go across.

Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only click and drag screen one on that option menu up and down (or move it to the other side). There's no other way to do what you want, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Opinion: I'm not sure that would be desirable.

### Like a desk with cut edges

On my desk I have my left monitor in portrait mode and my right in landscape, correctly aligned in the display settings. Since the height difference is huge, if Windows were to reposition the cursor proportionally, then the window that I am dragging would suddenly jump by 4 inches when the cursor gets on the other screen. It doesn't make any sense!

In my case it feels natural -like using a desk with non-standard edges- because my monitors are the same size and resolution

### The problem of DPI scaling

With screen of different DPIs like yours, what I think you'd need is Windows to know the DPI and seamlessly scale windows between them. If that were the case, placing a window right in the middle of the bezel line would form a continuous window like it does in my setup.

Unfortunately, we're not there yet. Windows 8 has a preliminary support for this but support is limited and is initially intended to make high-DPI Surface tablets work as a second monitor, not to make fine adjustments between 2 monitors of similar resolution.

Hopefully, with the coming of 4K monitors, MS and application developers will be obligated to support better dynamic scaling as the norm.

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) which has [a setting called Mouse Management](http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/WindowManagement/) (in the Window Management tab) that helps with the solid monitor edge problem. It's not the proportional positioning you're hoping for, but it's better than nothing. This feature is NOT included in the free version, so you'll have to pony up for it.

Or, if you know how to write code and you're feeling especially crazy, you can use something like [Libpointing](http://libpointing.org/) and raw mouse input to implement it yourself...