# Move mouse proportionally between different resolution (and DPI) displays

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse, dpi, 4k-resolution

I have three displays, a 4K display flanked by two 1080p displays. Physically, these monitors are roughly the same size. Furthermore, Windows 10 handles the DPI scaling of the 4K monitor separately from the 1080p monitors just fine. So while it appears as such to Windows

[image: Display setup]

the real layout is three monitors of equal size side by side.

The problem is that the mouse keeps getting caught on the edges of display 2 and three when dragging from display 1. I would like the mouse to continue onto display 2 or 3 regardless of which part of the left or right edge of display 1 the mouse touches.

This question has been asked before (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/793787/have-mouse-move-proportionately-between-two-screens)) and a common answer is to suggest that this behaviour is intentional on the basis that mouse movement should reflect different size displays. Such an answer is not appropriate as it doesn't consider DPI and scaling.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: So basically, you want to make it such that if your mouse is at e.g. 30% of the monitor height on the 1080p display and you move your mouse across monitors, it stays at 30% height on the 4k monitor?  The question you linked in your question already says that this isn't supported yet.

Comment: Right now, I care less about the details of where the mouse ends up, and more about the fact that the mouse stops moving completely unless I aim for display 2 or 3. The monitors are the same physical size, so you can't see where you have to aim. It's really jarring. I want the mouse to appear on the next monitor regardless of which percent of the left or right edge it hits. I am aware that I will probably not find a solution native to Windows. I'm hoping some free third party-solutions exist.

Comment: It is a basic featured missing in Windows. Hello Microsoft designer leader? Very annoying!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Perhaps **LittleBigMouse** could help you out? It's an alpha application, but it seems to be focusing on the issue you're having.

> DPI Aware mouse move across screens
>
> Allows accurate mouse screen crossover location within multi dpi
>   monitors environment. It is typically useful when using a 4k monitor
>   and a full HD side by side.

Github:
https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse

Download (Releases):
https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/releases

Comment: This is great! It is exactly what I was looking for. There's a little bug, where, if one of my screens is duplicated on a fourth monitor, the mouse can't decide which monitor to "snap" to, but I was able to mitigate the issue with some fiddling of the duplicated monitor position.

Comment: Definitely let the developer know on his Github page so he can try to fix the issue for the future! It seems like it's still being actively developed.

Comment: I found that if I placed the duplicated monitor on top of the original, there was no more issue. The program could use a bit more documentation, but otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: Does it have any GUI? By the description it looks like what I need, but I don't see any window, settings or any difference after installation. I'm running Win 10.

Comment: yes, it does have a GUI. Simple but nice:
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/C8ZTCuf)

Comment: TO DISPLAY FUSION USERS: This worked after you disabled all the mouse movement options in display fusion

Comment: To enable the desired function in the LittleBigMouse, activate the Allow Corner Crossing checkbox.

Answer (score 7):

There's new solution available in case anyone will find it useful - [Cursr](https://cursr.app), allows to customise mouse transition between all screens

Comment: It appears that you have recommended this app multiple times.  Please disclose if you are simply a satisfied user or have an affiliation with this app.

Comment: this works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

https://www.displayfusion.com/ has a feature that will mostly resolve this; it's very simplistic implementation. I have version 9.3 - not sure when it was added. **NOTE: DisplayFusion is not free.**

DisplayFusion > Settings > Mouse Management > Prevent mouse cursor from snagging on unaligned monitor edges

Comment: Looks like you covered all the bases for a software recommendation post. +1. (You may like to read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/q/5329) for more info.)

Comment: Today I stumbled upon this, my own answer, while trying to solve this problem again... and find it lacking. While the features I mention above are helpful in their own right, they do not provide "DPI aware" or anything resembling proportional transition. The most glaring example of why this is frustrating is that if you transition from the top of a larger resolution monitor onto a smaller, you arrive at the top, but then if you transition back, you arrive near the middle of the larger. It's jarring and annoying when working near the transition if you dip over accidentally.

Answer (score 5):

So, I had the same problem. 
TLDR; Due to lack of open source apps, (LittleBigMouse didn't work, DisplayFusion isn't free), I ended up writing a small application that does the job. 
Find it here: https://gitlab.com/rich4rd.macwan/mousemapper/tree/stable

I have two monitors, one 4k and one FullHD, both of almost same physical dimensions. The mouse movement between the two screens was a pain, because the 1080p vertical resolution of the 2nd screen(I have placed it on the right), is half the 2160p vertical resolution of the 4K screen on the left. Since I didn't find any free application for this, I decided to write it on my own.

It's a pretty simple tray application, that uses a mouse hook for getting the global mouse position and mapping it when it moves from one screen to another based on the resolution of the screens. Ideally, I should have put the mouse hook in a different dll (as suggested by microsoft), but I wanted something quick and dirty and it works. And it works only for two screens. Maybe if this application finds use, I will release a newer version with enhancements.

Hope it finds some use for people like me. It is not production level, but works fine for my case. Just putting it here if someone needs it :)

Comment: Did not work for me =/ Maybe because one monitor is 100% dpi and the other uses 125% scalling? Lastest Win 10. Little Big Mouse did work. Thanks for sharing your project though. =)

Answer (score 0):

[Continuous Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/continuous-mouse/9p6nts4k5425) is another simple alternative. It allows you to define exactly the transitions between monitors.

I designed this software with efficiency and having multiple monitors in mind.

[image: Example configuration for the to solve the problem]